# Operation on object makes changes on others

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I need a little explanation. Operation on one object makes changes on others, for example:

```
aa = Classifier("aa")
bb = Classifier("bb")

aa.print_table()
{1: 6, 2: 26}

bb.print_table()
{1: 6, 2: 26}

aa.addValue(3)

bb.print_table()
{1: 6, 2: 26, 3: 1}
```

Here is part of my class:

```
class Classifier:

classTable = {1:0} 
default = 0
classTable_size = 0
def __init__(self, q):
    a = 1
    self.name = q

def addValue(self, i_index):
    self.classTable.setdefault(i_index, self.default)
    self.classTable[i_index] += 1
    self.classTable_size += 1

def print_table(self):
    print(self.classTable)
```

If I define variable on the top of class (before constructor in this case) it will makes it "static" or I have error in my class? I was thinking defining variables this way makes them only available from own object.

I am very new in python.

Comment: You should read about class variables, and instance variables, Python's "static" concept is not _exactly_ the same as Java's o C#'s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

example:

```
class A:

    data = {}

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)

class B:

    data = {}

    def __init__(self):

        self.data = {'B': 5}

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)
```

in class `A` an instance does not own a `data` on its own; it is 'static' and can be accessed with `self.data` as well as `A.data` (that is how python looks up variables in an object: if `self.data` does not exist, python will look for `A.data`); both reference the same dictionary. changes to `self.data` (or `A.data`) will affect all instances:

```
a = A()
a.data.update({'A': 3})
print(a)  # -> {'A': 3}
aa = A()
print(aa)  # ->  {'A': 3}
```

except if you add a fresh `data` member for an instance; this one will belong to the instance only:

```
aa.data = {}  # data references now this empty dict and not A.data anymore
print(a)  # -> {}
print(aa) # -> {'A': 3}
```

in `class B` every instance gets its own fresh dict in the 'constructor' 
`__init__` -- even if there is a 'static' `data` member. changes in one instance do not affect other instances. `self.data` is now a different object than `B.data`.

usually it is a bad idea to have a class variable (`B.data`) and an instance variable (`self.data`) with the same name...

maybe [this](https://www.toptal.com/python/python-class-attributes-an-overly-thorough-guide) is worth reading. and there is a lot more information about python out there...